# How to change Customer Id and Order ID?

Tags: php, magento

Currently CustomerID's start at 1 while the first Order generated has `OrderID` `100000001`.

Is there any way of altering these fields, so the first customer created has
customer number `900000001` and the first order created has `OrderID` `900000001`?

Answer (score 1):

By changing the `increment_last_id` in `eav_entity_store` table, you can control the starting number of customer number, Order Number, Invoice Number, and shipping Memo Id.

Comment: Mind that this only works if you enabled the human-friendly customer ID under System > Configuration > Customer Configuration > Create New Account Options > Generate Human-Friendly Customer ID.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to alter the `AUTO_INCREMENT` of the table **before** adding new customer or order:

```
$magento_db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$magento_db->query("ALTER TABLE customer_entity AUTO_INCREMENT = ".$desiredId);
```

Comment: It only changes the customer increment id, not customer id

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code to *Phpmyadmin* to change the Order Number

```
UPDATE eav_entity_store
INNER JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
SET eav_entity_store.increment_last_id='XXXXX'
WHERE eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='order';
```

Replace the X‘s with your desired **order number**

for more detail you can go to this link for that:
[click here](http://bestforstore.com/magento/order/changing-shortening-order-increment-id-magento.html)