# How to start with a different Customer ID in Magento?

Tags: magento

In Magento Community v1.5.1.0, how would one go about setting the starting (or next) Customer ID? By default, the first Customer ID is 1. I need to start at Customer ID 300000 after clearing out test data before moving a store into production.

Order, Invoice, Shipment, and Credit Memo ID's can be changed by updating the appropriate values in the eav_entity_store, but (contrary to the information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410824/magento-change-customer-id-and-order-id)) there is not an increment entry for Customer ID there.

I scanned the database for a "customer"-related table that would achieve the same thing as eav_entity_store but no dice, and my Google-Fu failed as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I thought it was not possible in magento, But it will done by MySql query. Run the below query manually and you will get the user id starts from 300001

```
ALTER TABLE customer_entity AUTO_INCREMENT = 300001;
```

Comment: Ah... didn't think to look there. This tests out great... thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

There is no increment for customer in `eav_entity_store` but one can be created, perhaps in a module's install script...

```
$customerType = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->loadByCode('customer');
Mage::getModel('eav/entity_store')

    // customer increments are not per store so store_id is 0
    ->loadByEntityStore($customerType->getId(), 0)

    // increments are varchar, not ints
    ->setIncrementPrefix('3')
    ->setIncrementLastId('300000')
    ->save();
```

Comment: Thanks clockworkgeek! I've been utilizing your Magento skills for a while now... glad you're out there! I used Sankar's suggestion to just directly update AUTO_INCREMENT on customer_entity... I've created some new customers and their ID's are checking out. I'm assuming this ultimately does the same thing except in code rather than manual MySQL? (With the exception of the Increment Prefix addition)

Comment: The two methods are not quite equivalent. Sankar's affects the numeric `entity_id` (`$customer->getId()`) field but mine affects the textual `increment_id` (`$customer->getIncrementId()`) field. Use whichever is most convenient.